# Firestore Document error - Only static members can be accessed in initializers

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I want to get  Products added to cart by user.So i am trying to get documents based on uid(Documents named as uid)
But i am getting error 
**Only static members can be accessed in initializer**

Code:

```
class CartDataBase{
 FirebaseUser user;
 final FirebaseAuth _auth=FirebaseAuth.instance;

 void getUid()async
 {
  user=await _auth.currentUser();
 }
 final CollectionReference cart1 = Firestore.instance.collection('users').document(user.uid)//Only static members can be accessed in initializer
.collection('CartProducts');

     List<Checkout> _checkout(QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
      return snapshot.documents.map((doc) {
       return Checkout(
        original: doc.data['original'] ?? 999,
        image: doc.data['image'] ?? 'Error',
        name: doc.data['name'] ?? 'Error',
        quantity: doc.data['Quantity'] ?? 'N/A',
        identifier: doc.data['identifier'] ?? 'qwerty',
        price: doc.data['price'] ?? 999,
        iPP: doc.data['IPP'] ?? 999,
        uPQ: doc.data['UPQ'] ?? 999,
       );
      }).toList();
     }
     Stream<List<Checkout>> get CartProducts {
      return cart1.snapshots().map(_checkout);
     }

    }
```

[Screenshot for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k64c3.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem in your code can be found here:

```
final CollectionReference cart1 = Firestore.instance.collection('users').document(user.uid).collection('CartProducts');
```

There is no way you can assign that to the variable without waiting for it to finish fetching the document. You have to call await method first before you access it. We can solve this with the `await` keyword

```
final CollectionReference cart1 = await Firestore.instance.collection('users').document(user.uid).collection('CartProducts');
```

Since you cannot call async in your class, you have to convert it into a function as well as call that function in `initstate()` which gets called before your ui builds.

```
getDetails() async {
 final CollectionReference cart1 = await Firestore.instance.collection('users').document(user.uid).collection('CartProducts');
 //other things here
}

//place this below your widget build
@override
void initState() {
  getDetails();
  super.initState();
}
```

Comment: without async i can't use await and also i can't add async in this class